# Como colocar dentro de uma variável somente o texto que foi selecionado dentro de uma textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

Com

```
var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value;
```

consigo tudo que está na tetxarea que tem esse id, mas e se eu quiser um texto parcial?

Por exemplo o texto todo é esse:

**Alemanha comprou o jogo contra o Brasil**

Se eu selecionar apenas "comprou o jogo", gostaria que minha var tivesse esse conteúdo.

**Acrescentado (11/5/15):**

Bem, com o "mouseup" o alert funciona, mas assim, se eu simplesmente precisar colocar o valor da seleção dentro de uma variável com

```
 var textoSelecionado = showSelection(this);
```

para depois tentar usar este valor?

Meu objetivo final é poder colocar tags HTML ao redor do texto selecionado.

No entanto se eu clicar no link/imagem/botão que realize esta função automaticamente o texto deixa de ser selecionado e pelo que testei a função "showSelection" passa a não ter mais efeito.

Eu imaginei uma forma de tornar funcional isso:
ativando e desativando os botões, então se estiverem ativos ao selecionar o texto no "mouseup" ele sofre as alterações. Se não tiverem ativos não mudam. Seria como controlar se uso ou não a função showSelection. Isso creio que consigo fazer, mas gostaria de reter o texto selecionado para usá-lo ao clicar em um botão ou link.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement#Insert_HTML_tags_example

Comment: Legal, mas é cross browser? pelo que vi na caixa não está marcado a maioria dos navegadores.A não ser que nãos e refira a isso.

Comment: Acredito que funcione a partir do IE9 visto que são utilizadas as propriedades `selectionStart` e `selectionEnd` e o método `setSelectionRange`.

Comment: Isso não chega a ser um problema, mas nos demais browsers funciona?

Comment: Sim, os outros navegadores (firefox, chrome, safari, opera) suportam estas funcionalidades (só não sei quanto as versões mobile).

Comment: Já até adaptei o esquema que comentei na pergunta para ativar e desativar os botões, mas essa alternativa que você mostrou pode ser mais prática. Obrigado, vou testar.

Comment: @Oeslei funcionou em todos nabegadores, valeu, como o que estou construindo é para uso de adm, mesmo que não funcione em browsers mais antigos, é só pedir para o usuário atualizar todos os browsers para última versão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontrei [uma resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275825/2256325) que adaptei. Assim com esta função podes ir buscar o que está selecionado.

HTML

```
<textarea name="" id="texto" cols="30" rows="10">Texto de exemplo</textarea>
```

JS

```
function showSelection(textComponent) {
    var selectedText;
    // IE version
    if (document.selection != undefined) {
        textComponent.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = sel.text;
    }
    // Mozilla version
    else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined) {
        var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
        var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
        selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
    }
    return selectedText;
}

var textarea = document.getElementById('texto');
textarea.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    var textoSelecionado = showSelection(this);
    if (textoSelecionado) alert(textoSelecionado);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a1tc9984/

Comment: Isso eu conheço, mas não quero todo o texto, quero parcialmente.

Comment: @IWannaKnow mudei a resposta para só dar o texto selecionado.

Comment: Grato, vou estudá-la e já retorno.

Comment: Já tinha visto algumas dessas funções e lido sobre esse problema de que não há nada crossbrowser, mas li em páginas antigas do Google, imaginei que na atualidade já haveria algo que resolvesse isso. Acrescentei um texto a pergunta.

Comment: @IWannaKnow é isto que pretendes? -> http://jsfiddle.net/tLbysg4p/

Comment: Isso eu já fiz. Depois que você mostrou as funções ficou fácil e até acho que seja uma solução viável, mas eu falava de selecionar um texto e modificá-lo ao clicar em um botão.

Comment: Eu usei o "replace" e também ativo ou desativo um botão para que esta função só funcione se o botão desta tag estiver ativado.

Comment: Você viu o link que o @Oeslei postou? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement#Insert_HTML_tags_example

Comment: @IWannaKnow sim, vi. Isso é uma tecnologia que ainda não está implementada nos browsers. Pode ser que daqui a uns anos seja comum usar. Por enquanto só sei da maneira que coloquei.

Comment: Eu agradeço já foi de grande ajuda, mas testei aqui e funcionou a tecnologia do link.

Comment: @IWannaKnow testa também no IE versão 9, 10 e 11, e testa Safari (Mac) e Firefox. Acho que não vai funcionar na maioria desses.

Comment: Funciona em todos esses: Chrome, FF, IE 11, Safari e Opera. Não tenho como testar nas versões mais antigas, pois atualizo todos os browsers.